# How do I set permissions for web locations in web.xml?

Tags: servlets, http-status-code-403

I have seen websites where accessing www.example.com/js returns a 403 error.

My web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403.html</location>
</error-page>
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404.html</location>
</error-page>
```

But I get Error 404 instead of Error 403 when I access /js directory(or whichever directory for that purpose).

How do I make web.xml to generate Error 403 when a specific folder is requested? I am using GlassFish Server 4.1.1.

Comment: Did you check Glassfish Global Level? check below link may you will find the solution. https://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/12/07/customized-error-pages-for-glassfish-v3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Objective was solved by adding an index.jsp file in folders I wanted to raise Error 403.

index.jsp:

```
<% response.sendError(403);return;%>
```